# Как сделать автоматическое создание кастомной модели после регистрации в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть своя модель `Profile`.

*models.py:*

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='user_images')
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='+79999999999')
    tg = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='@имя_пользователя')
    access_telegram_master = models.BooleanField(default='0')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'Профайл пользователя {self.user.username}'
```

При регистрации я использую стандартную форму `Django`, после регистрации модель `User` заполняется, мне нужно, чтобы и моя модель `Profile` создавалась автоматически, и подставлялись значения, которые указанны в `default`.

*forms.py:*

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserOurRegistration(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserOurRegistration, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "Имя*"
        self.fields['last_name'].label = "Фамилия*"
        self.fields['username'].label = "Адрес электронной почты"
        

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться сигналом [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

***models.py:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_or_create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        try:
            instance.profile.save()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Код также позволяет редактировать `Profile` через `User`.